# set invoice expire time

Tags: lifetime-sales

I need to set expire time of a custom gateway invoice to be the same as the [Pending Payment Order Lifetime](https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/sales/order-pending-payment-lifetime.html).

So that, how to get the "pending payment order lifetime" programmatically.

eg: i want to replace the `$cofig->getPendingPaymentOrderLifetime();` with right code

```
$lifetime = $Conf->getPendingPaymentOrderLifetime();

$currentDate = new \DateTime('now');
$currentDate->modify("+$lifetime minutes");

$expiryDate = $currentDate->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$ScopeConfigInterface = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface');

$lifetime = $ScopeConfigInterface->getValue('sales/orders/delete_pending_after', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
```